# Function result in list box

Tags: php, list

In an attempt to keep php code seperated from html as much as possible in my pages, I'm trying to create a function which can be used to populate list/drop down boxes on other pages.
  Using msqli, I have queried my table "acc_vat_rates! and selected the two fields I am interested in,  "vat_rate_id" and "vat_rate_name"
I then loop through the result and populate an array called $vatratearray, code below...

```
<?php 

function vat_rates(){
    $conn = new mysqli("192.168.1.81", "root", "", "cloudoneaccountsdb");
$queryvat = "SELECT vat_rate_id,vat_rate_name FROM acc_vat_rates ORDER BY vat_rate_id";
$resultsvat = $conn->query($queryvat);
//SET UP AN ARRAY NOW
$vateratearray = array();
while ($rowvat= $resultsvat->fetch_assoc())
    $vatratearray[] = $rowvat['vat_rate_id']." "." ". $rowvat['vat_rate_name'];
//print_r($vateratearray);

foreach($vatratearray as $key => $value)
//echo "<p>{$value} <?br></p>";
echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
}

?>
```

This function is stored in a page called "global_functions.php to be included in other pages
All of the above works fine. I then use the function "function vat_rates() as the option value for a list box on an other page, however, this is where my problems begin. When the function populates a listbox it displays the record_id and the name alongside each other, this is ok but when I post the selected line, it also posts the "id" and the "name" which is not what I require. I only want the "id" to be posted for inclusion in the DB.

I've been at this for a fair while, so any help would be appreciated.
Thanks...
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just change your while loop and remove the foreach:

```
while ($rowvat= $resultsvat->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<option value="'.$rowvat['vat_rate_id'].'">'.$rowvat['vat_rate_name'].'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 while ($rowvat= $resultsvat->fetch_assoc())
        {

            array_push($vatratearray, 
              array('vat_rate_id' => $rowvat['vat_rate_id'], 
                    'vat_rate_name' => $rowvat['vat_rate_name']

              ));

        }    

        foreach($vatratearray as $key => $value)
        {
        echo '<option value="'.$value['vat_rate_id'].'">'.$value['vat_rate_id'].'  '$value['vat_rate_name'].'</option>';
        }
```

You can improve this code a lot....you can even create the options inside the while loop; just like the other answer XD

Saludos ;)